# ios Default downloaded pdf file path and location

Tags: ios, path, directory

Please Help me 
i am new in ios development 
client need pdf file attachment in app 
so if user download any pdf file in iphone ,ipad from using gmail ,dropbox ,skydrive. so i need all default downloaded pdf location 
i am using this code but this is not helpful, this is get a my app location but i have need default download directory .

```
 NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
 NSString * documentsPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
 NSLog(@"%@",resourcePath);
 NSLog(@"%@",documentsPath);
 NSError * error;
 NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:&error];   
 NSLog(@"%@",directoryContents);
```

Please share your Valuable Knowledge 
Thankyou in Advance .  .  .  .

Comment: I think since iOS 7 you are not required to go to the directory with downloaded file. You can only do some stuff in your app directory. But you can register a filetype for you app and for example open the pdf from email with your app. Then the pdf file will be copied to your app directory and you can do with it what ever you want.

Comment: One more thing: there is probably no Download directory with such a stuff. Every app like dropbox and so one download the files in they own app directory.

Comment: but sir , It is possible to get default ios download file directory Path , i think it is easy to me. When i get pdf path then i will pdf file convert in base64 , and send to server

Comment: ok. its means , only one option to copy pdf file in my app directory, 
so i search on google " How to pdf file copy in my Directory "

Comment: look also for : "Associate a File Type with your App" and "FileSharing". Could be useful, if you like to copy the pdf directly into your app via iTunes.

Comment: Thankyou For Help, you are so helpful Person . 
Nice to talk to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not default path in iOS where PDF files are saved. All apps are sandboxed and files associated with that app are stored within that sandbox and cannot be accessed by other apps.

If you want your app to be able to open PDF files you will need to register your app as an app that can open PDF files. To do this read the [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Introduction/Introduction.html) this talks about [Registering the File Types Your App Supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1).

This will allow apps the use the [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDocumentInteractionController) to open the PDF in your app.